# How to fix a program from having to run as administrator to be able to print in adobe air?

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am having a problem with printing in a adobe air application using the [as3 printjob](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html) package.

The problem is that the example works 100% as expected until I package the application into a .air file or as a native application. When I do this I can no longer print anything until I right click on the application and run it as administrator.

Is there a way to package the application so it doesn't have to be run as administrator in order for it to be able print? Is there something I should be setting in the mxml file?

Thank you!

Comment: Printing is done without having to run as administrator for sure. If it's the case for you your OS might have a settings preventing apps from running print jobs without the proper permissions.

Comment: That is what i thought to. The print box shows up but it doesn't do anything unless the program is running as administrator.

Comment: It started working but not a clue as to why or what changed. I didn't change anything in the code. I'll keep playing and see if i can find out why.